# Mixing system implies induced transformation is mixing

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am wondering if the following is true:

Suppose $T:X\to X$ is a transformation with probability measure $\rho$. Suppose tht $T$ is mixing. i.e., $|\rho(A\cap T^{-n}B)-\rho(A)\rho(B)|\to 0$

If $Y\subset X$ with positive measure and $R:Y\to \mathbb{N}$ is the first return time to $Y$ such that $T^{R(y)}(y)\in Y$ for all $y\in Y$, we can define the induced transformation by $F=T^R:Y\to Y$.

Can we say that $F$ is mixing (with respect to $\rho|_Y$)?

Comment: is it obvious that $F$ preserves $\rho\mid_Y$?

Comment: For example, take $X = \{1,2\}$ with uniform measure, $T(1)=2,T(2)=1$, $Y=X$, $R(1) = 1, R(2)=2$. Then $F(1)=2,F(2)=2$, so $F$ is not measure-preserving.

Comment: Have a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160955/mixing-property-of-first-return-map. I edited the question to refer to the first return time.

Comment: @mathworker21 there is a theorem in "Laws of Chaos" by Boyarsky and Gora which confirms $F$ preserves the measure. I can not remember the number off the top of my head.

Comment: @JohnB this is perfect, thanks!

Comment: @MrMartingale you needed first return time.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y=X$, then the first return map is $T$, so $F = T$.  The answer is that the induced transformation $F$ is not necessarily mixing.  The easiest example I can think of is $T$ equal to the staircase transformation: https://community.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-03/S0002-9939-98-04082-9/S0002-9939-98-04082-9.pdf.  This transformation is mixing due to staircases whose heights increase by one being added infinitely many times.  To get the induced transformation $F$, fix one of the columns and let $Y$ be just that column without including any other staircases.  The transformation $F$ will be rigid and therefore not mixing.